# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle File Upload (Profile Pic) Tips?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-forms

I'm about to embark on trying to add a profile picture field to my User entity in a symfony2 project I'm working on which uses `FOSUserBundle`. I have a feeling that this should be really simple, however, I've not found any useful documentation explaining how to do it.

At the moment, I'm planning on adding an unmapped field to my form object (which I've extended from the generic `ProfileEdit` form) which takes an uploaded file. I'll then create an event listener for either `FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_SUCCESS` or `FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_COMPLETED`, which will take the form, handle the file upload and persist the path of the uploaded file (with methods to get the public URL and absolute path) to my User object, before adding a message to the Response flashbag to say it was either successful or unsuccessful. Is this really the correct/best practice way to do this? Or am I missing something? Is this functionality really not included yet in the FOSUserBundle? If so I've not found the docs for it, but would love it if it was....

Any help / tips / voodoo advice would be so greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems the alternative to this is to add an event listener to the form itself. Does anyone have any experience as to which is preferable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, it turns out I was getting lost answering this question: the file upload needn't be handled by FOSUserBundle per se, rather by Doctrine. I added a property to my User entity which is not persisted, but which is simply used by the form to edit a user's profile. In the code below this property is `$profilePictureFile`. Lifecycle callbacks then ensure that this file is copied to the relevant location before the entity is persisted (and similarly when edited and when deleted).

Still, I thought I'd post an answer alongside my code here to help others who find themselves wanting to add profile pictures to a user in FOSUserBundle in the future.

The relevant documentation is:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.rst

```
<?php
// DAWeldonExampleBundle/Entity/User.php
namespace DAWeldon\Example\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\SecureRandom;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $lastEdited;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your surname.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     */
    protected $surname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your forename.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     */
    protected $forename;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $nickname;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="2048k")
     * @Assert\Image(mimeTypesMessage="Please upload a valid image.")
     */
    protected $profilePictureFile;

    // for temporary storage
    private $tempProfilePicturePath;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $profilePicturePath;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set surname
     *
     * @param string $surname
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSurname($surname)
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get surname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSurname()
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    /**
     * Set forename
     *
     * @param string $forename
     * @return User
     */
    public function setForename($forename)
    {
        $this->forename = $forename;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get forename
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getForename()
    {
        return $this->forename;
    }

    /**
     * Asks whether the user is granted a particular role
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isGranted($role)
    {
        return in_array($role, $this->getRoles());
    }

    /**
     * Set nickname
     *
     * @param string $nickname
     * @return User
     */
    public function setNickname($nickname)
    {
        $this->nickname = $nickname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nickname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNickname()
    {
        return $this->nickname;
    }

    /**
     * Get the best way to address this person
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBestAddress() {
        if (empty($this->getNickname()) and empty($this->getForename()) && empty($this->getSurname())) {
            return $this->getUsername();
        }
        elseif (empty($this->getNickname())) {
            return $this->getForename().' '.$this->getSurname();
        }
        else {
            return $this->getNickname();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the file used for profile picture uploads
     * 
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     * @return object
     */
    public function setProfilePictureFile(UploadedFile $file = null) {
        // set the value of the holder
        $this->profilePictureFile       =   $file;
         // check if we have an old image path
        if (isset($this->profilePicturePath)) {
            // store the old name to delete after the update
            $this->tempProfilePicturePath = $this->profilePicturePath;
            $this->profilePicturePath = null;
        } else {
            $this->profilePicturePath = 'initial';
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the file used for profile picture uploads
     * 
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getProfilePictureFile() {

        return $this->profilePictureFile;
    }

    /**
     * Set profilePicturePath
     *
     * @param string $profilePicturePath
     * @return User
     */
    public function setProfilePicturePath($profilePicturePath)
    {
        $this->profilePicturePath = $profilePicturePath;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get profilePicturePath
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getProfilePicturePath()
    {
        return $this->profilePicturePath;
    }

    /**
     * Get the absolute path of the profilePicturePath
     */
    public function getProfilePictureAbsolutePath() {
        return null === $this->profilePicturePath
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->profilePicturePath;
    }

    /**
     * Get root directory for file uploads
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getUploadRootDir($type='profilePicture') {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded
        // documents should be saved
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir($type);
    }

    /**
     * Specifies where in the /web directory profile pic uploads are stored
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getUploadDir($type='profilePicture') {
        // the type param is to change these methods at a later date for more file uploads
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
        // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/user/profilepics';
    }

    /**
     * Get the web path for the user
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getWebProfilePicturePath() {

        return '/'.$this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->getProfilePicturePath(); 
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUploadProfilePicture() {
        if (null !== $this->getProfilePictureFile()) {
            // a file was uploaded
            // generate a unique filename
            $filename = $this->generateRandomProfilePictureFilename();
            $this->setProfilePicturePath($filename.'.'.$this->getProfilePictureFile()->guessExtension());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates a 32 char long random filename
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function generateRandomProfilePictureFilename() {
        $count                  =   0;
        do {
            $generator = new SecureRandom();
            $random = $generator->nextBytes(16);
            $randomString = bin2hex($random);
            $count++;
        }
        while(file_exists($this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$randomString.'.'.$this->getProfilePictureFile()->guessExtension()) && $count < 50);

        return $randomString;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     * 
     * Upload the profile picture
     * 
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function uploadProfilePicture() {
        // check there is a profile pic to upload
        if ($this->getProfilePictureFile() === null) {
            return;
        }
        // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
        // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
        // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
        $this->getProfilePictureFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->getProfilePicturePath());

        // check if we have an old image
        if (isset($this->tempProfilePicturePath) && file_exists($this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->tempProfilePicturePath)) {
            // delete the old image
            unlink($this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->tempProfilePicturePath);
            // clear the temp image path
            $this->tempProfilePicturePath = null;
        }
        $this->profilePictureFile = null;
    }

     /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeProfilePictureFile()
    {
        if ($file = $this->getProfilePictureAbsolutePath() && file_exists($this->getProfilePictureAbsolutePath())) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }



    /**
     * Set lastEdited
     *
     * @param \DateTime $lastEdited
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLastEdited($lastEdited)
    {
        $this->lastEdited = $lastEdited;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastEdited
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getLastEdited()
    {
        return $this->lastEdited;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function setLastEditedValueAsNow() {
        $this->setLastEdited(new \DateTime());
    }

}
```

And of course, the profile form looks like this:

```
<?php
// DAWeldonExampleBundle/Form/Type/ProfileFormType.php
namespace DAWeldon\Example\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ProfileFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // add your custom field
        $builder->add('username')
                ->add('surname')
                ->add('forename')
                ->add('nickname')
                ->add('profilePictureFile');
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_profile';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'readypeeps_user_profile';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I have a question here. If you want to show the users photo in the profile edit template, how do you do that? How do you call User entity methods inside a twig template. Cheers

Comment: Hey cute.S, I think this is a question more related to bundle inheritance. You'll have to "override" the bundle, then create a new template, within the bundle's namespace, for your new form and controller. I hope the following docs help! http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html

Comment: (I've had to reply really quickly, do reply if you've a question!)

Comment: It's worth noting that by default sonata edit profile or fos user profile edit forms do not set  enctype to "multipart/form-data". Without this that solution won't work.

Comment: @DomWeldon  I am getting this error `The file could not be found.` when i upload image.

Comment: nice dude, fixed that.